Shell substring extraction from the end
I have this shell variable that gives me a string followed by the an HTTP return code.
# echo $response
good200

The script runs mostly on a BusyBox Shell and it has no Printf %q formatting.
# echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

# sh --help
BusyBox v1.25.1 (2024-02-26 21:43:31 EST) multi-call binary.

The string can have a value of good or bad, and the last 3 characters are the HTTP return code.
I want to extract the sub-string and the return code, but shell is not cropping the string.
When I try to echo the $response variable with a negative position number modifier, the value is simply not trimmed.
# string=${response:3}  # 3 IS OK AND THE STRING IS TRIMMED
# echo $string
d200

# httpcode=${response:-1:3}  # -1 DOES NOTHING
# echo $httpcode
good200

If I add a space before the position number or use parentheses, the shell throws a "bad substitution" error.
# echo ${teste: -2}
-sh: syntax error: bad substitution

# echo ${teste:(-2)}
-sh: syntax error: bad substitution

How do I capture the actual string and HTTP code correctly?

BTW, if you want to print response as a whole in unambiguous form, use declare -p response to do that. Again, echo $response is buggy and should never be trusted. See I just assigned a variable but echo $variable shows something else and Why is printf better than echo? as a few relevant starting points.

Thanks you for your tips. I don't think Printf changes the output in this scenario, and it's somewhat limited in the environment I'm testing. I have added more context to the question to make it clearer.

Ah. sh is not (guaranteed to be) bash at all (when it is bash it's in a feature-reduced compatibility mode), and ${var:offset:len} is a bash extension, not POSIX-specified functionality; so this is indeed quite considerably clearer now.

(see substring in sh returns bad substitution -- it's completely legal for /bin/sh to refuse the operation outright; as much performance hit as there is to using expr, that's where one ends up when portability is critical)

btw, even in busybox ash, you still want to quote your strings.

...since you don't have printf %q, consider printf '%s' "$response" | xxd as an alternate way to get an unambiguous printout of a variable's contents. (busybox can be compiled without xxd, but I'm assuming you've got the full complement of standard options).

Why not simply doing a ${response##*[^0-9]}? This should be expanded to just 200.
